# Two questions about the neighborhoods of locally compact and connected metric spaces.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M$ be a complete, connected and locally compact metric space which contains more than one point. Does each point of $M$ belong to a non-degenerate connected subset of $M$ whose diameter is arbitrarily small?

If $M$ is compact and $B$ is a closed ball of $M$ whose radius is positive, does there always exist a connected subset of $B$ which contains the center of $B$ and a point of the boundary of $B$?

Comment: In the 2nd q you mean a connected subset of B which contains a center of B, not the center. Centers are not always unique.

Comment: I thought that in order to specify a closed ball in a metric space, one had to specify a particular center and a particular radius.

Comment: We can have $B(x,r)=B(x',r')$ or  $Cl (B(x,r)=Cl (B(x',r')$ or $\{y:d(y,x)\leq r\}=\{y:d(y,r')\leq r'\}$ with $x\ne x'$ and $0<r\ne r'.$  It doesn't affect your Q, and the usage of the term may be more a matter of style.

Comment: I have found an article by E. Miller on pages 150-157 of the Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society for 1940, which contains a theorem of A. Mulikin  that implies my second question has a "Yes" answer-unless there is some Booboo in my reasoning.